# Using C# to log into RoR (Devise) app

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

I have a RoR web app that currently leverages Devise for user authentication.  From what I understand, passwords are stored using the BCrypt algorithm and include both a hashed password and password_salt, which is stored for each user in my users table.

In conjunction I have a Microsoft Office add-in that was developed in C#. I need to be able to log users in from the add-in by calling to the users table and validating the password they entered in the add-in against the hashed password stored in the users table.

Unfortunately when I attempt to use BCrypt via C#, I'm unable to successfully log into the app from the add-in.  I've looked all over for examples on how to achieve this, but have come up short.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  And/or do I also need to parse the password_salt?  Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

EDIT:  I see that BCrypt no longer requires a separate password_salt.

EDIT2: I'm using devise-encryptable, and in my initializers/devise.rb, I have:   config.encryptor = :authlogic_sha512
and a config.pepper, which is set to a long hash.  Should C# now use sha152 instead of BCrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you add an API to your application that allows your to send username/password pairs over HTTP and receive an authentication token when successful.

This would be much easier than attempting to interface with the database directly, as devise has already done all the hard work for you.